# Using an alert in the Firefox add-on builder

Tags: firefox-addon

I'm trying to write my first Firefox extension using the [FF add-on builder](https://builder.addons.mozilla.org/). I don't understand why it seems my code isn't running at all as neither `alert` pops up. Why doesn't `alert("Main");` create a popup?

**main.js**

```
alert("Main");
var data = require("sdk/self").data;
var pageMod = require("sdk/page-mod");
pageMod.PageMod({
  include: "*",
  contentScriptFile: data.url("noredirectlinks.js"),
  contentScriptWhen: "ready"
});
```

**noredirectlinks.js**

```
alert("Content script");
var allLinks = document.getElementsByTagName("a");    
for (var i=0, il=allLinks.length; i<il; i++) {
    elm = allLinks[i];
    if (elm.getAttribute("onclick")) {
        elm.onclick = null;
    }
    if (elm.getAttribute("onmousedown")) {
        elm.onmousedown = null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `alert` in `main.js` cannot show anything in your browser. The main addon code has not access to the browser page. To access to the content, you have to use [*content scripts*](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/dev-guide/guides/content-scripts/index.html) (as your second script).

The `alert` in `noredirectlinks.js` should work. I would first test again without the `alert` in `main.js`. Then you must be sure that the file is located in `data` folder. Is it the case?

There could be also another error in a code you didn't provide which could explain why the addon is not executed. Is there other code or is that everything?

Comment: I deleted the alert in `main.js` thanks for the explanation there. 

When I tested it again the alert in `noredirectlinks.js` worked. However at first I didn't think it did because I tested it on a local HTML file. For some reason that didn't match the `"*"` pattern but other websites show the alert.

Yes it's in the data folder and this is everything.

I don't think it has any errors as I was able to get it working as a Chrome extension. However, something is acting differently than I expect because if I google something and click on the link an `onmousedown` event still happens.

Comment: I'm also new here, since LaurentG answered the question as stated should I repost a new one to figure out why I'm not nullifying `onmousedown` events as desired?

Comment: You should access to the document using `content.document`. See [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Extension_Frequently_Asked_Questions#Accessing%5Fthe%5Fdocument%5Fof%5Fa%5Fwebpage%5Fdoesn%27t%5Fwork).

Comment: If I'm correct, I don't think this is worth a new question. Otherwise a new question for this other problem would be, I assume, the usual way to handle this on StackOverflow.

Comment: Thanks LaurentG! That's exactly what I was missing. Sadly I don't have even the 15 rep to give you an upvote, but if someone else sees this please give LaurentG one on my behalf.

Comment: You already accepted the answer what give already 15 points. Thank you.